# Import multiple CSVs without headers into single R data frame

Tags: r

I'm attempting to import a large amount of CSV files with no headers into a single data frame in R using the following code, but it results in the error message "names do not match previous names". I'm guessing this function requires the data to have headers. What function can I use for this process that allows for importing data without headers?

```
filedir <- setwd("C:/test/")
file_names <- dir(filedir)
your_data_frame <- do.call(rbind,lapply(file_names,read.csv))
```

Comment: @ZheyuanLi; do you need to add `skip=1` if the data does not have headers? Wouldn't `header=FALSE` be enough

Comment: @ZheyuanLi; hmm, could be, but Q does say *" large amount of CSV files with no header"*. I think the difficulty is that `read.csv` default is `header=TRUE`, hence lots of different headers as the first row of the data will be used.

Comment: @user20650 correct, there are no headers as I said. I completely forgot about the headers = FALSE function. That worked perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If at the moment your files have different headers, then I think we can use

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(file_names, read.csv, skip = 1, header = FALSE))
```

providing that all your files have equal number of columns and same data class. The `skip = 1L` ignores existing header in each file, while `header = FALSE` will automatically generates `V1`, `V2`, ..., as column names, consistent for all data frames.

But if your files have no headers, you just need to set

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(file_names, read.csv, header = FALSE))
```

---

Oh, as *user20650* kindly reminded, you need the second option.

Comment: Nice one Zheyuan Li!!